# Google analytics closed funnels for android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm looking for a way to create closed funnels for my android app. Most guides I found suggest I go to admin, and views column to create goals, but I don't see views column.
Is there some other place to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You followed the guidelines about Universal Analytics but you created a GA4 Property that haven't views). In this case you can set an event as convention in the events report, then create a funnel in Analysis report.

Anyway, if you want a Universal Analytics Property you have to create a new Property by click on 'show advanced option' and choosing that Property, as shown in following image:

[image]